# Everyone calls Electromagnetic Induced Transparencyan interference phenomenon, but is it also an interference phenomenon in classical systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, interference

[Electromagnetically induced transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetically_induced_transparency) is a hot topic in physics. However I'm curious about its mechanics in physics. Physicists think that it's a phenomenon of interference from transition of two states which is explained by the atomic levels of the system. Could it also be interference in a classical system? If it could, what would be the mechanics of their interference? Or what would interfere with what?

The paper below describes a classical system which displays EIT in a classical system which may help you save your time in understanding.

Garrido Alzar, C. L., Martinez, M. A. G. & Nussenzveig, P. Classical analog of electromagnetically induced transparency. American Journal of Physics 70, 37 (2002). ([arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0107061v1))

[image: Coupled oscillators system]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EIT and the mechanical analogy you posted are examples of coupled resonator systems. In the RLC circuit, the system includes two RLC circuits that are coupled. The EIT system consists of a pair of two-level systems that couple to a single shared level. An RLC circuit and a two-level system both exhibit resonance effects: the energy transferred into the system depends on the frequency of the drive. The interference occurs between the power transferred by the probe field (applied voltage in the RLC circuit) and the power transferred from the pump field (the right-hand loop in the RLC circuit). These two halves of the system try to drive the system and compete to the point of canceling out at zero detuning.

Comment: In the coupled oscillators system, it's like interference between driving power and motion power transfered from the second oscillator. Is that OK?